# How to limit instantiation of class and methods in it -Java

Tags: java, interface, abstract-class, abstract, class-structure

```
@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__({ @Inject }))
public class TransactionManager {

    private final TransactionHelper tnxHelper;

    public void createTransactions(List<Details> details) {
        tnxHelper.createTransactions(details); 
    }
}

@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__({ @Inject }))
public class TransactionHelper {

    private final A a;    
    private final B b;

    public void createTransactions(List<Details> details) {
        //Some logic
    }
}
```

So in the above code, I want TransactionManager to be the main class and every interactions related to Transaction should go via it, like `createTransactions`.

So how can i make `TransactionHelper` as hidden? So that no one can use this class apart from `TransactionManager`?

Also is there any way to only make `createTransactions` in `TransactionHelper` as hidden, rather than hiding the whole class.

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/what-is-the-difference-between-public-protected-package-private-and-private-in

Answer (score 1):

Is the usage of Nested classes resolve your problem ?
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

```
class TransactionManager {
  // you cannot use the class TransactionHelper outside the TransactionManagerClass 
  // you need an instance of TransactionManager to have an instance of TransactionHelper 
  // so within static methods here you cant use it directly
  private class TransactionHelper {
  }

  void dooo() {
    TransactionHelper t = new TransactionHelper();
  }
}
```